# How to get number of files in a directory and subdirectory from a path in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, readline

I Have a `folderName.txt` file which has a list of all the folders path.
How can i get the total count of the total number of files present inside that folder path.

For one path i'm able to do this like this.

```
new File("folder").listFiles().length.
```

But the Problems is i'm not able to read the path from the `folderName.txt` file .

i'm trying this

```
File objFile = objPath.toFile();
     try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                             new FileReader(objFile))){
          String line = in.readLine();

           while(line != null){

            String[] linesFile = line.split("\n");
```

But when i'm trying to access the linesFile array i'm getting an exception.
like `linesFile[1]`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:.

My question is why i'm getting the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ?.
and How could i read individual directory path and total number of files inside it. Is there way to read the total number of files in a subdirectory too.

folderName.txt has a structure like this.

> E:/folder1
>
> E:/folder2

Comment: `in.readLine();` reads one line, so it can't have line separator `\n` in it, which means `split("\n")` is redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception because :

> readLine() method reads a entire line from the input but removes the
>   newLine characters from it.so it's unable to split around \n

Here is the code That does exactly what you want,.

I have a `folderPath.txt` which has a list of Directory like this.

> D:\305
>
> D:\Deployment
>
> D:\HeapDumps
>
> D:\Program Files
>
> D:\Programming

This code gives you what you want + you can Modify it according to your need

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    List<String> foldersPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folderPathFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ankur\\Desktop\\folderPath.txt");

    /**
     * Read the folderPath.txt and get all the path and store it into
     * foldersPath List
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folderPathFile));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        foldersPath.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    /**
     * Map the path(i.e Folder) to the total no of 
     * files present in that path (i.e Folder)
     */
    Map<String, Integer> noOfFilesInFolder = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String pathOfFolder:foldersPath){
        File[] files2 = new File(pathOfFolder).listFiles();//get the arrays of files
        int totalfilesCount = files2.length;//get total no of files present
        noOfFilesInFolder.put(pathOfFolder,totalfilesCount);
    }

    System.out.println(noOfFilesInFolder);
}

}
```

Output:

`{D:\Program Files=1, D:\HeapDumps=16, D:\Deployment=48, D:\305=4, D:\Programming=13}`

Edit : This counts the total number of files present inside the subdirectory too.

```
/**This counts the
         * total number of files present inside the subdirectory too.
         */
        Map<String, Integer> noOfFilesInFolder = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String pathOfFolder:foldersPath){
            int filesCount = 0;
            File[] files2 = new File(pathOfFolder).listFiles();//get the arrays of files
            for (File f2 : files2){
                if (f2.isDirectory()){
                    filesCount += new File(f2.toString()).listFiles().length;

                }
                else{
                    filesCount++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(filesCount);
            noOfFilesInFolder.put(pathOfFolder, filesCount);
        }

        System.out.println(noOfFilesInFolder);
    }
```